# Wordpress Dashboard - Restricting Access

Tags: dashboard

I'm new to WordPress and a bit confused with something. I'm trying to build a classified marketplace type of website for myself. I am NOT building this for a "client". I will probably be using a hack of several different plugins as my coding skills are not up to par.

Eventually I will hopefully have lots of users who will be composed of buyers & sellers.

My question pertains to the WP dashboard. When buyers/sellers sign up for my site, will they be able to see the WP dashboard? I would prefer that they NOT be able to access a back-end dashboard at all let alone a WP branded one. Is this possible? If so any clue as to how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the dashboard, however, will not be the same according to the role of the user. Contributor won't see much of the menu, for example. A subscriber can only manage its own profile.

Try to set up different users with different roles to see how the WP Admin is displayed for those users.

Then you could try to define your own users roles, change menus and layout, or even refuse access to dashboard. There's a lot of functions and API to help you on this : check the Codex for a start : http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities and http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is also a plugin available which can help you `redirect` users to a certain URL once they try to open the dashboard.

Plugin Name:

`Remove Dashboard Access`

Link to the Plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/

Comment: thanks Omar will check out. So otherwise is accessing the dash pretty much a default thing? So in my case every user will be able to access the dash unless I do something about it?

Comment: Yes, accessing dashboard is the default thing. You have to install this plugin to redirect the users whenever they try to access the dashboard.